# MXD defined symbology not retained

Tags: arcpy, layers, layer-file

I'm trying to create some layers from feature classes located in the geodatabase. The MXD is created, symbology on feature classes defined within ArcMap, but for some reason my symbology is not carried over to layers. Do you know why?

```
import arcpy
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
gdbLoc = cwd + "/../Zion.gdb"
lyrLoc = cwd + "/../symbology/"
mxdLoc = cwd + "/../Assignment3.mxd"

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdLoc)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, 'Layers',)[0]

for fc in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):

    outlayer = str(fc)+"_lyr"
    layerfile = os.path.join(lyrLoc, str(fc) + '.lyr')
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, outlayer)
    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(outlayer,lyrLoc+str(fc))

    print '{0} created.'.format(fc)
```

Comment: Do you need the MakeFeatureLayer_management line?  Could you just SaveToLayerFile?

Comment: MakeFeatureLayer is used to create a layer from a dataset (i.e. feature class) but you are creating layer objects called `fc` from your ListLayers and then trying to make feature layers from layers instead.  I'm surprised that does not throw an error.

Comment: So should I be using ListFeatureClasses instead to list all feature classes in my geodatabase?